# Sample selection in difference-in-differences

Tags: least-squares, causality, unbiased-estimator, difference-in-difference, treatment-effect

I have a dependent variables with a significant amount of zeros (and the share of zeros is different between the control and treatment groups, and changes between the pre- and post-treatment periods). I do observe a pre-treatment parallel trend of the dependent variable (when including the zeros).

My problem is simple: is a standard diff-in-diff biased in this case (and why)? If yes, what can be done?